# 05 Buick Rainier engine reduction how to fix?

Tags: buick, electronic-control-module, clicking

I'm having a problem getting the engine power reduction to go away.  Usually I just have to turn off the vehicle and crank it back up and it's fine. Not this time.  We have tried a number of things, and it's stuck. Can anyone suggest a bypass or quick fix?

The PCM has a fast clicking upon turning of the key before it will let you crank it up. What could fix this? Do I need a replacement pcm? Sounds like a quiet machine gun and last for about 30 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "reduction"?

Comment: The light on the instrument panel signals engine reduction. It wont let me go over 20 mph

Comment: Found a clicking sound coming from pcm

Comment: I believe what you're experiencing is a "limp home mode" where the vehicle is protecting itself.You need to get the codes read to see what's going on or causing the limp home mode. You can possibly reset the PCM by disconnecting the battery for 20 minutes (and press the brake pedal to bleed any residual energy in the system). Upon reconnect, it might come out of the mode, but it's doubtful. Usually if there's a big enough problem to get into this mode, it won't want to come out until you fix the issue. Get the codes read and we can go from there.

Comment: I believe we may have found the problem the throttle body seems to be needing a replacement

Comment: How did you discern it needs a replacement?